# How i take value of StaleElementReferenceException with "GetAttribute" or ".Text" to validate Assert.IsTrue in selenium

Tags: .net, selenium, specflow

I try take value of StaleElementReferenceException with the code:

```cs
var valuePerfil1 = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'Analistas') and contains(@class, 'x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-id x-unselectable')]")));

wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));

try
{
    valuePerfil1.Click();
    selectValue.Click();
}

catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
{
  String recebe = valuePerfil1.Text;
  _valuePerfil1 = recebe;
}
```

but when comparate in `Assert.IsTrue(_valuePerfil1.Contains("Analista"));` this error is present: `_valuePerfil1 era null`

How i take this value with `valuePerfil1.GetAttribute("Text");` or `valuePerfil1.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

A `StaleElementException` means the IWebElement no longer references a valid HTML tag or Document Object Model node in the browser. The `_valuePerfil1` field is null, because the `valuePerfil1` variable is not tied to an HTML tag loaded in the browser, so its `Text` property is likely `null` as a result.

I would expect `_valuePerfil1.Text` to be `null` or throw an exception when the `_valuePerfil1` element is "stale".

Comment: How i do this ?

Comment: @JorgePereiradaSilvaJunior: You need to find the element again.